# jQuery Tools Dateinput + jQuery Validation Plugin - Not working in Webkit

Tags: jquery, webkit, jquery-tools, jquery-validate

I have a simple form that uses the [jQuery Tools Dateinput](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/dateinput/index.html) and the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). The problem is that the validation works in IE and FF but not Chrome or Safari.

HTML:

```
<form id="testform" method="post">
    <label for="deliverydate">Select delivery date<span class="req">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="date required" id="deliverydate" name="deliverydate" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.date").dateinput({
        format: 'dd / mm / yyyy',
        trigger: true,
        min: -1
    });

    $("input.date").change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });

    $("#testform").validate();
});
```

I have a [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/allyreid/AxWK3/14/) here with an example.

Any ideas what could be causing this? It's driving me crazy!!

Comment: What is the error? I just tried your jsfiddle link in chrome and FF9 and couldn't see any difference. - Edit, scrap that, I'd not clicked the submit button, it errored for me when I selected 31/1/2012 and submitted..

Answer (score 0):

When ever I have a problem with specific browsers, adding Modernizer (http://www.modernizr.com/download/) always seem to do the trick!

Comment: I'm not sure Modernizer is useful in this particular problem as I'm not looking for a specific feature that the browser supports but thanks for the suggestion.